# OculusWorldDemo just black on Ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, oculus

I downloaded the Oculus SDK for Linux version 0.3, relinked the libudev library with `sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0` (see [error on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288821/how-do-i-resolve-a-cannot-open-shared-object-file-libudev-so-0-error)), ran the *ConfigurePermissionsAndPackages.sh* script and then successfully compiled the SDK with `make`.

When i start the demo with `sudo ./OculusWorldDemo.sh` the window opens, but stays black. The log seems to indicate that the device is recognized:

```
$ sudo ./OculusWorldDemo.sh 
OVR::DeviceManagerThread - running (ThreadId=0x7f71447fe700).
OVR::DeviceManager - initialized.
*** SensorFusion Startup: TimeSeconds = 1405808704.635467
OVR::Linux::HIDDevice - Opened '/dev/hidraw0'
                    Manufacturer:'Oculus VR, Inc.'  Product:'Tracker DK'  Serial#:'I2M8G3PGPC29'
OVR::SensorDevice - Closed '/dev/hidraw0'
OVR::Linux::HIDDevice - HID Device Closed '/dev/hidraw0'
OVR::Linux::HIDDevice - HIDShutdown '/dev/hidraw0'
OVR::Linux::HIDDevice - Opened '/dev/hidraw0'
                    Manufacturer:'Oculus VR, Inc.'  Product:'Tracker DK'  Serial#:'I2M8G3PGPC29'
Sensor created.
```

Why wouldn't it display any graphics?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
On the Oculus Rift Forums, others [reported it as well](https://developer.oculusvr.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=6359). It seems the only solution so far is to downgrade to SDK version 2.5.